# BIP Excel output removing zeros from decimal

Tags: bi-publisher

I have a BIP Data Model and Report with Excel (.xls) as the template type. There are a couple of fields that have zeros at the end of the decimal and for some reason they are being stripped out when viewing in Excel. I want to be able to preserve this.

[image]

In the above example, you can see the XML output from the data model is showing the value with the entire value (204.820).

However when I view the downloaded Excel file, this is how the data is displayed:

[image]

You can see that the 0 was removed from the end of the decimal.

How can I ensure the 0 is not removed? Is there a specific XML function I can apply to preserve this?

Comment: This is an Excel thing. The zero is still there, but excel is removing it in the display.

This might work for trailing zeroes too.
https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20E-Business%20Suite/2014395_1.html

Comment: @RanjithR I already had tried this by setting the Excel .xls template column to be Text type, but when the output is generated the 0 is still getting removed at the end. Is there some XDO-like function I can apply to the field reference to prevent this from happening?